# How to remove unwanted rows from dataframe?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

If you look on baseball-reference.com and click on teams and batting, you can see they have options to convert the tables to CSVs but how do I get them when the URL does not work with `read.csv()`

I am trying to import batting data with the `rvest` package from specific teams off of baseball-reference.com. I only want to include the fielders and omit the pitchers, the repeating column names, and the team totals that the website generated from the data. If I can just use the CSV I wouldn't have this problem but `html_table()` only grabs the original table from the website and removing the columns with values only messes up the data.

```
library(rvest)
#Goals
#Remove unwanted rows
#Remove pitcher batting stats

#San Fransisco Giants
giantsBatting <- read_html('https://www.baseball- 
reference.com/teams/SFG/2019-batting.shtml#team_batting::none')
giantsCSV <- giantsBatting%>%
  html_nodes('table')%>%
  html_table()
giantsDF<-as.data.frame(giantsCSV)
giantsDF<-giantsDF[!(giantsDF$Pos=='P'& giantsDF$Pos=='Pos'),]
print(giantsDF)
```

I want the output to have one set of column names (the table has three sets on row 9-10 and later for the pitchers) and remove the pitchers and total team stats.

The actual output doesn't omit all pitchers and does not remove the extra column name headers.

Comment: You cant have both 'P' and 'Pos' in the same row.  You may need `!giantsDF$Pos %in% c("P", "Pos")`

Comment: you can get your intended output if you change `&` to `|`, `giantsDF[!(giantsDF$Pos=='P' | giantsDF$Pos=='Pos'), ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the logic looking for both 'P' and 'Pos' on the same row by using `&`.  It gives an output of all `FALSE`, by negating (`!`), this gets converted to all `TRUE` and hence the full dataset is returned.

Instead, for a vector of values with `length` greater than 1, use `%in%` and then negate (`!`)

```
giantsDF1 <- giantsDF[!giantsDF$Pos %in% c("P", "Pos") ,] 
nrow(giantsDF1)
#[1] 36

nrow(giantsDF)   
#[1] 71
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped with the table but how would you get the CSV option? The HTML for that on the website is '#csv_team_batting' but fails to be read when I use `html_nodes('#csv_team_batting') %>% html_text()` Sorry if these questions are basic knowedge I forget a lot of the syntax